# Legend information in shapefile

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, legend, openlayers-2

I am a novice to the field of GIS so please forgive my ignorance.

I am required to plot a shapefile (.shp) on a basemap which is an openlayers map. The shapefile is published in GeoServer as a wms layer.

How do I extract the legends information from the shapefile so that I can display it on the webpage?

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer supports the WMS GetLegendGraphics request.
See: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html